# Is it possible to add boid behavior to a Geometry Node point distribution?

Tags: particles, physics, constraints, geometry-nodes, vector

Specifically, I would like to know what the vector is to the closest other point created in geometry nodes. I created them with the standard Point Distribute. This is basically Boid behavior, where each "particle" is attempting to maintain an ideal distance from other particles.

It feels like it should be very possible; but I'm not sure it's been implemented yet. Perhaps someone here with more familiarity with geometry nodes can help me out?

Comment: Do you want the Vector, or do you just want to define a min distance?

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to add realistic-ish flow behavior to a point map driving a mud flow. A minimum distance would work, especially if I could just add a Hooke force to it; but I've already implemented a velocity parameter so a vector would be ideal. It currently looks good, but a minimum distance would make it look better.